# Cypress ERROR: Could not resolve "module"

Tags: cucumber, cypress

My test cases were working fine yesterday but today when I try to run my test cases with new changes it is running my test cases with old changes instead of new updates.

I tried running 'cypress run' to debug, it throws an error

```
Error: Build failed with 1 error:
node_modules/cypress/index.mjs:1:19: ERROR: Could not resolve "module"
```

I updated cy.wait(10000) to cy.wait(20000)

Error:
`  Running:  ERPNextCompany.feature                                                          (1 of 2)
X [ERROR] Could not resolve "module"

```
node_modules/cypress/index.mjs:1:19:
  1 │ import module from 'module'
    ╵                    ~~~~~~~~
```

The package "module" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node. Are you trying to bundle for node? You can use "platform: 'node'" to do that, which will remove this error.`

Logs:

```
The error was:

Error: Build failed with 1 error:
node_modules/cypress/index.mjs:1:19: ERROR: Could not resolve "module"
    at failureErrorWithLog (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New folder\cypress_udemy\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1636:15)   
    at C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New folder\cypress_udemy\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1048:25
    at runOnEndCallbacks (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New folder\cypress_udemy\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1471:45)     
    at buildResponseToResult (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New folder\cypress_udemy\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1046:7)  
    at C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New folder\cypress_udemy\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1075:16
    at responseCallbacks.<computed> (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New folder\cypress_udemy\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:697:9)
    at handleIncomingPacket (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New folder\cypress_udemy\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:752:9)    
    at Socket.readFromStdout (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New folder\cypress_udemy\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:673:7)   
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)

This occurred while Cypress was compiling and bundling your test code. This is usually caused by:

- A missing file or dependency
- A syntax error in the file or one of its dependencies

Fix the error in your code and re-run your tests.
```